# Is it possible to convert a linear system in an ODE of higher order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The opposite direction is quit simple. But under which circumstances is it possible to convert a system of first order ODE of dimension n into a single ODE of order n?

Answer (score 8):

This is not a complete answer (yet), and I encourage other folks to build on it:

---

A set of [*autonomous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) coupled linear first-order ODEs can always be written in the form
$$
y' = A y
$$
where $y$ stands for a vector of $n$ functions and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.  By differentiating both sides further, we obtain
$$
y'' = A y' = A^2 y \\
y''' = A y'' = A^3 y \\
\vdots \\
y^{(n)} = A^n y.
$$
Now, we can take an arbitrary linear combination of these $n$ derivatives to obtain an expression of the form
$$
(c_n y^{(n)} + c_{n-1} y^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_1 y' + c_0 y) = (c_n A^n + c_{n-1} A^{n-1} + \dots + c_1 A + c_0 I)y.
$$ 
But if we pick the $c_i$ coefficients as the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (i.e., $c_n$ is the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ in the polynomial $\det(\lambda I - A)$), then by the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) the right-hand side of this equation will vanish.  This implies that for any autonomous system, each component of $y$ will individually satisfy the $n$th-order equation 
$$
c_n y_i^{(n)} + c_{n-1} y_i^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_1 y_i' + c_0 y_i = 0.
$$
where the $c_n$ coefficients are those of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

This is, of course, only a sufficient condition;  certainly there are non-autonomous systems that can be converted into a single $n$th-order equation as well.  It is also possible for the $n$th-order equation to possess solutions that are *not* solutions of the original system;  for example, blindly applying this procedure to the system
$$
y_1' = y_1 \qquad y_2' = y_2
$$
i.e., $A = I$, we obtain the equation
$$
y_1'' - 2 y_1' + y_1 = 0,
$$
and similarly for $y_2$.  However, there are solutions to the latter equations that are not solutions to the original system.

Comment: It shows some audacity to first say “always”, then immediately restricting the answer to *linear* systems. But perhaps this result is not too difficult to extend to nonlinear systems? I imagine it would be a local result, relying on the linear case through linearization. (But I like your answer, and upvoted it. I wasn't aware of this result or its proof, and it feels like I should have known it, like forever.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: To be fair, the question title does specify "linear systems", though the question statement itself does not.  (Also, I've backed off on my "always" statement due to the caveats that I thought of immediately after posting.  [*L'esprit du post button*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier), I suppose.)

Comment: Thank you for the very elegant answer. When I wrote the body-text I was actually aware that it was more general.

Comment: Ah. I tend not to pay much attention to the title, as it is too often rather uninformative.